# Populating a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtree

I'm having an array of objects of class A which contain an array of objects of class B.
I've got quite a few questions: (Coding examples would be of great help)

1. How can I use a `JTree` with parent node as Object A and children node as B's and populate it?
2. Assuming that the entire `JFrame` is divided into two panels(one containing the `JTree` and another `JPanel` which displays object's attributes corresponding to the option selected on the `JTree`) how can I  make this happen? As of now, I'm able to hard-code the values into the `JTree`.

I've searched a **lot** for examples on the net but was able to find only basic examples.

This is what I've done so far:

```
public class A {
int a1=10;
int a2=20;
B bobj[]=new B[2];
A(){
   bobj[0]=new B();
   bobj[1]=new B();
}
}

class B {
int b=30;
}
```

In my Jtree code:

```
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;

public class try1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 static A a2=new A();
/** Creates new form try1 */
public try1() {
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    Tree = new javax.swing.JTree();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Tree.setModel(a2);
    Tree.setAutoscrolls(true);
    Tree.setRootVisible(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Tree);
    Tree.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");
    Tree.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 655, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 569, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 463, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 151, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 236, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(21, 21, 21))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(473, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(43, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 569, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    a2=new A();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           new try1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
public javax.swing.JTree Tree;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
// End of variables declaration

}
```

I found this example[here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/JTreeObject.shtml)
1. Since the eg's initial format is an array of strings,they're using the hastable. Since I'm using a class of objects(A) which contains objects of B, how should I do it(I'm getting an error above).
2.I've attached the layout of my Frame. I've hardcoded the Jtree in the screenshot. What should I do so that if I click on any Jtree node, I'm able to view the details on J[image]TextField near it?

Comment: How about 1) showing us what you've tried and 2) clarifying *exactly* where you're stuck. Right now you're asking very general and vague questions and it would be hard to answer this without writing a complete tutorial. You know the drill for a tough programming problem: break the project down into small tasks and then solve each small task. I suggest that you give this a try, and then if stuck ask as specific a question as possible. Luck!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels- Sure, I'll edit my question right away. thanks!

Comment: *"Coding examples would be of great help"* Likewise evidence of effort would be of great help.

Comment: Exactly, and not to mention that there are tons of examples already out there on how to create and fill a JTree, so knowing what you've tried and where exactly you're stuck is essential if we're to have a prayer of helping you. I look forward to seeing your edit.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: You're using A as if it were a TreeModel class, but it does not implement the TreeModel interface or extend from DefaultTreeModel.

Comment: Also try creating this small code without NetBeans code generation. Many of us can't test your code if you use this, and also doing it on your own teaches you invaluable lessons on how to code Swing.

Comment: Also, have you read the API and tutorials about using the TreeNode interface? I have looked at the sample code given by the [Java Tree tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), and they seem anything but "*basic*" to me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and others- Thanks for the info! I figured a way to do it! This happened because I moved out of the IDE and actually wrote the code instead of fixing the Swing Containers/Controls. I shall post the exact code asap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your program fragment and image, you may want to start by studying the [`TreeDemo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TreeDemo) example discussed in [*How to Use Trees*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). Related examples may be found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#eg).